# How do I replace page enumeration with load more button via Jquery?

Tags: jquery, pagination, magento2

I want to make a function load more in my order.

Here is description image 
[image]

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you just make it a scroll down menu?
Add this CSS code to the div that has the orders list:

```
.YourDiv{
  max-height: [YourDivHight]px/%/vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

**NOTE:** *We can't just write whatever code you want, we need to know what is your code.*